# Traffic source issue in Google Analytics 4 while using Google Tag Manager in Nuxt3

Tags: google-tag-manager, google-analytics-4, nuxt3

I have implemented Google Tag Manager in my Nuxt3 application by creating a plugin called gtm.client.ts with code presented below (my tag replaced by Xs).

All tags are working in Google Tag Manager Assistant and Google Analytics also gets data and events. The only problem that I noticed is in Traffic Source that is presented in Google Analytics as almost all traffic is presented as Direct traffic. This is definitely not the case as I can see that the numbers of Direct Traffic align with the data in Search Console. Also the POST requests to region1.google-analytics.com seem to look OK at least when I check it in my browser.

Has anyone faced similar issue?

My Google Tag Manager script implementation:

```
import { defineNuxtPlugin, useHead, useRuntimeConfig } from '#imports'

export default defineNuxtPlugin(() => {

  useHead({
    script: [{ 
        children: ` 
            window.dataLayer = window.dataLayer || [];
            function gtag(){dataLayer.push(arguments);}

            if(localStorage.getItem('consentMode') === null){
                gtag('consent', 'default', {
                    'ad_storage': 'denied',
                    'analytics_storage': 'denied',
                    'personalization_storage': 'denied',
                    'functionality_storage': 'denied',
                    'security_storage': 'denied',
                });
            } else {
                gtag('consent', 'default', JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('consentMode')));
            }`,
    }]
  });

   useHead({
    script: [{
        children: `(function(w,d,s,l,i){w[l]=w[l]||[];w[l].push({'gtm.start':
        new Date().getTime(),event:'gtm.js'});var f=d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0],
        j=d.createElement(s),dl=l!='dataLayer'?'&l='+l:'';j.async=true;j.src=
        'https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtm.js?id='+i+dl;f.parentNode.insertBefore(j,f);
        })(window,document,'script','dataLayer','GTM-XXXXXXXX');`,
        type: 'text/javascript',
    }],
    noscript: [{
        children: `<iframe src="https://www.googletagmanager.com/ns.html?id=GTM-XXXXXXXX"
        height="0" width="0" style="display:none;visibility:hidden"></iframe>`,
        tagPosition: 'bodyOpen'
    }]
  }) 

})
```